# Implementing AES algorithm using Arduino

Tags: implementation

I am using an Arduino board to implement the AES Algorithm:

I am having a large data of length approximately 500 bytes. I did all the basic stuff in implementing this AES Algorithm. I am getting partial Results.

Please help me implement this.

Comment: Voting to close as this is obviously an implementation issue. If you decide to post on StackOverflow, please be sure to create [an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)